# Google maps working a lot and getting slower on Kitkat

Tags: android, google-maps, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on an app that shows a lot of markers on a google map. To avoid the app working too slow i implemented the marker clustering system. Everything was working greate until i updated my testing device to kitkat, after that my google map never stops working and downloading data so it gets really slow showing this error in the LogCat:

```
Skipped x frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

and a lot of this messeges:

```
09-25 11:54:40.373: D/USER_EVENTS(14233): Event: type=113, status: ma, data: c=241
09-25 11:54:40.375: D/USER_EVENTS(14233): Event: type=113, status: mI, data: c=241
09-25 11:54:40.375: D/USER_EVENTS(14233): Event: type=113, status: mt, data: c=149
09-25 11:54:40.477: D/REQUEST(14233): Add Data Request: 108
09-25 11:54:40.479: D/REQUEST(14233): Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
09-25 11:54:40.479: D/REQUEST(14233): Open Connection
09-25 11:54:40.868: D/REQUEST(14233): Processing DataRequest: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@4254a520
09-25 11:54:40.868: D/REQUEST(14233): Processing DataRequest: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.af@42c41940
09-25 11:54:40.870: D/REQUEST(14233): DRD(25): 62|108, <1s, <1kb
09-25 11:54:40.870: D/REQUEST(14233): Close
09-25 11:54:40.871: D/USER_EVENTS(14233): Event: type=22, status: fb, data: 389
09-25 11:54:40.872: D/USER_EVENTS(14233): Event: type=22, status: lb, data: 391
09-25 11:54:40.873: D/USER_EVENTS(14233): Event: type=22, status: flbs, data: fb=389|lb=391|s=94
09-25 11:54:40.966: D/dalvikvm(14233): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1970K, 15% free 17925K/20956K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
```

Is this a known issue on kitkat?

How can i make the google map to work smoothly apart from clustering the markers?

Comment: If you're showing a lot of markers without clustering it's obvious that it will take a lot of resources to draw all of that.

Comment: As i said, im already clustering the markers, but when i zoom in even if just a few markers have to be displayed the app gets very slow.

Comment: Decrease the range of your data when you zoom in

Comment: I did already, but even if i zoom in on a place where there are any markers the app still gets slow as if it loads all markers regardless if they are shown on screen or not.

Comment: Then that means that you're showing an abusive amount of markers (or your marker resource is heavy) and you shouldn't be doing that. What is the point of displaying 300 markers on the screen?

Comment: I have almost 500 markers. When zoom is far from ground everything works fine because they are all clustered but when i zoom in, even on a place where there are no markers at all it starts working slow. Before kitkat i didnt have this problem. There has to be a way to make google maps works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it implementing the Viewport marker manager techniche, i have also created a guide here: [How to use Viewport Marker Management on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046253/how-to-use-viewport-marker-management-on-android)